# Knockout - dictionary with lists as values

Tags: knockout.js

I have data in C# Web Api controller with following structure:

```
Dictionary<string, List<Project>> projects ....
```

Key in dictionary is just month name - projects are grouped by months.

My knockout ViewModel:

```
function ProjectsViewModel(data) {
        var self = this;
        self.projects = ko.observableArray([]);

        for (field in data) {
            if (data.hasOwnProperty(field)) {
                self.projects.push(new DictionaryItem(field, data[field]));
            }
        }
    }

    function DictionaryItem(key, value) {
        this.key = ko.observable(key);
        this.value = ko.observableArray(value);
    }

    var viewModel;

    $(function() {
        var baseUri = '@ViewBag.ApiUrl';

        $.getJSON(baseUri, function(data) {
            viewModel = new ProjectsViewModel(data);
            ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
        });
    });
```

I want to present this data with knockout using one table with following format:

```
[key]
[project row]
[project row]
[key]
[project row]
[project row]
...
```

I'm trying to do this with following markup, using Knockout:

```
<table>
   <tbody data-bind="foreach: projects">
   <tr>
      <td data-bind="text: key"></td>
   </tr>
   <!-- ko:foreach: value -->
   <tr>
      <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
   </tr>
   <!-- /ko -->
   </tbody>
</table>
```

But it doesn't work - ot only produces "key" rows. How can I achieve what I want?
Maybe I'm doing this basically wrong and I should group data in my View instead doing this server side?

Comment: You have an extra `:` after `ko` in your second foreach the correct syntax is : `<!-- ko foreach: value -->`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix the syntax of your second foreach.

```
<!-- "ko foreach: value -->
```

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/DRhrQ/

Comment: thanks! this is crazy - I lost about 30 minutes on a syntax error :) Thank your for a fresh look :) I added working example to your answer!